# static class method or pure functions in node js

Tags: node.js, oop, functional-programming

due to my learning, I usually use static class methods and OOP more than pure function and functional programming. Some of my work mates dont understand why and I dont know wich way is better. This is a piece of code for example:

```
const DynamoDbHelper = class DynamoDbHelper {
    static getTableProperties(tableName) {
       ...
    }
    static async updateTableReadAndWriteCapacities(tableName, readCapacityUnits, writeCapacityUnits) {
        ...
    }
}
module.exports.DynamoDbHelper = DynamoDbHelper;
```

can also be write:

```
module.exports.getTableProperties = (tableName) => {
    ...
}
module.exports.updateTableReadAndWriteCapacities = async(tableName, readCapacityUnits, writeCapacityUnits) => {
    ...
}
```

Wich solution is the better in this case?

Comment: If both of them work equally well (which they should) it's opinion based

Comment: Mostly its just opinion based. I came from a PHP background and as such, share your liking for classes in javascript. But there really is no better way than the other. If you like the grassroots of javascript, use method 2, if you like a little bit of sugar on top, use method 1. Being new to javascript, I tend to cluch to new methods of doing things and opt for option 1

Comment: Static class methods are not OOP at all.

Answer (score 3):

Static-only class is antipattern in JavaScript. It's valid only in languages that don't support functions as independent entities.

If a class isn't intended to be instantiated and acts as a namespace, this is what modules are for. The second snippet is how this should be done.

Comment: And any advantage of method 2 over method 1 apart from personal opinion?

Comment: @NelsonOwalo It don't create a function (`DynamoDbHelper`) that will never be used.

Comment: TBH I would call it an antipattern in *all* languages. Those languages that don't support anything outside of `class` syntax are badly designed imo.